# What code would I use to get the hex value of a color when an alpha at about half transparency is applied?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, graphics, colors, hex

If I have a visual element (could be text or div with color fill, doesn't matter) and the color is set to black, **0x000000**, and it's alpha is set to **.4** or **.5** and the background is **solid white**, **0xFFFFFF**, the result would be a gray color. We can test this in Photoshop.

What I would like to know is what code would I use to get to that result?

I'm looking for something such as an equation:

```
newColor = foregroundColor * alpha * backgroundColor
```

Or something like in JavaScript, ActionScript or VBScript:

```
var color:uint = (0x888888 * .5) * 0x000000;
```

Part of the difficulty is solving this issue is the lack of fully understanding enough about hexadecimal and how it relates to color to solve it on my own.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: This is related to programming. I have updated the question. Please reopen

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Alpha Blending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending) algorithm from wikipedia:

> [image]