# What code would I use to get the value of a color when an alpha at about half transparency is applied?

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, colors, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What code would I use to get the hex value of a color when an alpha at about half transparency is applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14127060/what-code-would-i-use-to-get-the-hex-value-of-a-color-when-an-alpha-at-about-hal)

If I have a visual element (could be text or div with color fill, doesn't matter) and the color is set to black, **0x000000**, and it's alpha is set to **.4** or **.5** and the background is **solid white**, **0xFFFFFF**, the result would be a gray color. We can test this in Photoshop.

What I would like to know is what code would I use to get to that result?

I'm looking for something such as an equation:

```
newColor = foregroundColor * alpha * backgroundColor
```

Or something like in JavaScript, ActionScript or VBScript:

```
var color:uint = (0x888888 * .5) * 0x000000;
```

Part of the difficulty is solving this issue is the lack of fully understanding enough about hexadecimal and how it relates to color to solve it on my own.

**UPDATE**
Based on the answer below I've come up with this:

```
// set values
var topColorValue:uint = 0x000000;
var topColorAlphaValue:Number = .5;
var bottomColorValue:uint = 0xFFFFFF;

// get RGB
var redMix:int = ((topColorValue >> 16) & 0xFF);
var greenMix:int = ((topColorValue >> 8) & 0xFF);
var blueMix:int = (topColorValue & 0xFF);

// apply alpha to top color
if (alphaValue<1) {
    var colorPlusAlpha:uint = combineRGB((redMix * (1-alphaValue)), (greenMix*(1-alphaValue)), (blueMix * (1-alphaValue)));
}
else {
    colorPlusAlpha = topColorValue;
}

redMix = ((bottomColorValue >> 16) & 0xFF);
greenMix = ((bottomColorValue >> 8) & 0xFF);
blueMix = (bottomColorValue & 0xFF);

var secondColorPlusAlpha:uint = combineRGB((redMix * (alphaValue)), (greenMix*(alphaValue)), (blueMix * (alphaValue)));

var firstColorPlusSecondColor:uint = colorPlusAlpha + secondColorPlusAlpha;
```

The problem with the above solution is that it is off by 1. If the top color is **0x999999** and it's alpha is **.5** and the bottom color is **0xFFFFFF** then the result is **0xCBCBCB**. When getting that pixel or using eye dropper in Photoshop the value is **0xCCCCCC**.

Comment: Reposting your question to ignore close votes is not appropriate. If your question is on-topic enough, the other one will be reopened.

Comment: The other question was closed because the original readers did not think it related to programming. Instead of asking for clarification they decided to close it. I added new information.

Comment: I think that you are looking for [color composition formulas](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq17-compositionmodes.html). They will depend on what composition type you want. I don't know if making a JavaScript function implementing the corresponding formula would be useful for you.

Comment: According to the link, I think it would be alpha blending.

Answer (score 1):

IIU the functioning of the alpha channel correctly, it gives the mixing fraction between the color before and the color now added. This would mean:

```
colorVisible=colorNew*(1-alpha)+colorOld*alpha
```

A rough sanity check:

- `alpha=0%` gives `colorVisible=colorNew` which sounds OK
- `alpha=100%=1` gives `colorVisible=colorOld` which sounds OK too

Comment: I would add that it only works with grey or pure blue and black.

Comment: I'm doing some testing and it looks like that as well. I think it might need to pull out the r, g and b values and multiply those by alpha. Not sure yet. Trying this, var finalVisibleColor:uint = topColorValue * (1-alphaValue) + bottomColorValue * alphaValue;

Comment: THis was ofcourse meant as being per channel (R,G,B) !

Comment: Based on your code I think I found something that is working. It's off by 1 though so maybe you can see what I'm missing. Posting this info in the main post.

Comment: This looks to me like some fishy rounding: 99h=153d, 153*0.5=76.5, FFh=255d, 255*0.5=127.5, 127.5+76.5=204=**CCh**. I suspect, that a **int** multiplied by **float** 0.5 gives a rounded-down value. Retry with **float** mix values and round as late as possible.